# how to get the project path in eclipse?

Tags: java, servlets

I need to write the the processed data to a particular path within the project folder. When i tried this I got access denied error. Also this code is giving me weblogic server path. not the eclipse project path

```
FileOutputStream out;
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
out = new FileOutputStream(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
System.out.println("write_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
```

I want write the file to the following path:

`project-folder/war/write_demo.xlsx`

How do i do that?

Comment: Put the folder into new File().
out = new FileOutputStream(new File("project-folder/war/write_demo.xlsx"));

Comment: you are running your application from eclipse or deployed war in weblogic?

Comment: @Kanagaraj: i am deploying the war on weblogic and then running

Comment: That's why you are getting the weblogic path and it correct only...

Comment: i want to write demo.xlsx file to the following path: If print is the name of the project then print/war/demo.xlsx is path where i want to write. what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question it's quite old but I thought it might still be useful.

```
// Assuming that eclipseProject is a IJavaProject
IProject prog = eclipseProject.getProject();

for(String key: prog.getPathVariableManager().getPathVariableNames())
    System.out.println(key);
```

The code above will print out the keys to a Map that contains several useful absolute paths. In my case, the output is:

```
PROJECT_LOC 
WORKSPACE_LOC 
ECLIPSE_HOME 
PARENT_LOC
```

So the code to get the absolute path of the project is:

```
prog.getPathVariableManager().getURIValue("PROJECT_LOC").getPath()
```

This code is going to work also (and especially) if the project is not actually located in the workspace but it's located elsewhere and it has been imported.

Hope that it can be useful :)

Answer (score -2):

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

This Can be used to get project path in eclipse

Comment: Projects need not be located in the user home.

Comment: @SpaceTucker: System.getProperty("user.home") will return the user home. System.getProperty("user.dir") returns the directory in which the program is actually started.

Comment: user.dir gave me weblogic serve path. and user.home gave me c:\users\ron. Not want i needed

Comment: That statement just gives the server path, not the project path.